# Vuetify V-File-input with append-outer-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to change v-file-input icon and place the icon behind.
So I used "append-outer-icon" to change icon and place, but
If I click the icon nothing happen.
I waned to click the "append-outer-icon" and open folder like click the prepend-icon.
My sample code is below.

```
<template>
<v-file-input
                prepend-icon=""
                append-outer-icon="mdi-folder-open"
              ></v-file-input>
</template>
```

Could anyone advise me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with pure CSS.  Use `prepend-icon` only, along with:

```css
.v-file-input {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
.v-file-input {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <br /><br />
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input prepend-icon="mdi-folder-open"
             ></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a ref to the file input and trigger it using [`click:append-outer`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#click:append-outer) :

```
<v-file-input
                prepend-icon=""
                append-outer-icon="mdi-folder-open"
               ref="file"
              @click:append-outer="this.$refs.file.$el.querySelector('input').click()"
              ></v-file-input>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
methods:{
  open(){
 this.$refs.file.$el.querySelector('input').click()

 
  }
}
})
```

```css
#app{
width:200px;
padding:16px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-file-input prepend-icon="" append-outer-icon="mdi-folder-open" ref="file" @click:append-outer="open"></v-file-input>
</div>
```